# count how much Visitors in real-time on Specific page asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

What is the best way to build a Mechanism that count visitors in real-time on Specific page in asp.net?

is there a known Module that I can implement in my website?

I thought of a static class and ajax from that page that run every few seconds but how can I know the user is leaving the page?.

Any idea how to help me with that?

Thanks

Baaroz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/701975/A-real-time-visitor-counter-with-autorefresh-featu) article would definitely help.

Alternatively, you can also consider building the user counter page using SignalR, 
Refer [SignalR online counter sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536514/SignalRplusOnlineplusCounterplusSample)

Comment: the article  is exactly what I had in mind ,thanks a lot for this:)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, you can declare a variable in you Application_Start event in you global.asax file and on Session_Start increase that variable by 1 and on Session_End decrease it.

Comment: but how can I know on Specific page?

Comment: mmmm, I missed that part of your question. No you can't know on what page using this way.